# AVAudioPlayer and Button Presses

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Hey I'm designing an iphone app that programatically loads buttons into a scroll view and plays sounds. I have gotten the sounds to play in order, which is great, but whenever I try to press a button, it doesn't register the button press until the final sound in the sequence starts playing. Here's the code  in my main view controller where I play the AVAudioPlayer:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
for (menuCount = 0; menuCount < [ivrTree count]; menuCount++ ) {

    currentScript = [ivrTree objectAtIndex: menuCount];

    for (btnCount = 0; btnCount < [currentScript.menuChoices count]; btnCount = btnCount) {
        currentChoice = [currentScript.menuChoices objectAtIndex: btnCount];
        if (![thePlayer isPlaying]) {
            if (!mute) {
                [self playPromptAudiofromSRC:self src:currentChoice.audioSRC];
            }
            btnCount++;
        }
    }
}
thisMenuPlayed = true;

}
- (void)playPromptAudiofromSRC:(id)parent src:(NSString *)src {

NSURL *fileURL;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *audioPrompt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [defaults stringForKey:CONFIG_IVR_HOST], src];

if ([src isEqualToString:@""] || src == nil) {
    audioPrompt = @"silence1sec";
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:audioPrompt ofType:@"wav"];
    fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
} else {
    fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:audioPrompt];
}

AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (_audioPromptSound);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_audioPromptSound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_audioPromptSound);

//NSLog(@"Audio SRC: %@", audioPrompt);
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

[soundData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
                                                       fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:NULL];  
self.thePlayer = player;
[player release];
[thePlayer prepareToPlay];
[thePlayer setVolume:1.0f];
[thePlayer play];
}
```

I don't know why this only registers button presses after the whole thing plays. I am trying to implement a mute button and a way to "barge" in on the audio while it is playing essentially. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Adding a delegate:

In your .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
}
```

In your .m file:

```
thePlayer.delegate = self;
[thePlayer play];
```

As I can see there could be a problem in your animationDidStop, as it will iterate through all sounds regardless of what you do. I'll try and step through it line by line and explain what I'm after(and there will be some guesswork as I can't see your entire code).

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
// Iterate through array ivrTree elements.
for (menuCount = 0; menuCount < [ivrTree count]; menuCount++ ) {

    // Starting with currentScript = ivrTree objectAtIndex 0
    currentScript = [ivrTree objectAtIndex: menuCount];

    //Iterate through menuChoices, Starting with objectAtIndex 0
    for (btnCount = 0; btnCount < [currentScript.menuChoices count]; btnCount = btnCount) {
        //Set currentChoice to menuChoices objectAtIndex 0
            currentChoice = [currentScript.menuChoices objectAtIndex: btnCount];
        //Will try to run playPromptAudiofromSRC if thePlayer isn't playing. Will 1st run evaluate as false and therefor will play.
            if (![thePlayer isPlaying]) {
                if (!mute) {
                    [self playPromptAudiofromSRC:self src:currentChoice.audioSRC];
                }
        //Will increment btnCount to 1 when the audio has played through.
            btnCount++;
            }
        //If sound hasn't finished playing it will stay in the for loop and keep trying until first sound is done playing.
    }
//Will increment menuCount 1 and start the next for loop all over again.
}
thisMenuPlayed = true;
}
```

Can you see what I'm getting at? If you start instruments and check what's going on I'm pretty sure you will see a spike in activity that won't subside until all sounds has played through.
I think that the way this method is written it locks up your device. Hope it helps.

Comment: well I have an if ([thePlayer isPlaying]) before I call the playPrompAudioFromSRC method, so that it only increments btnCount and plays the next audio after the first one is done. Adding [thePlayer stop] didn't help. Also not sure what you mean by error handling

Comment: No I don't have either of those. Let me try that now

Comment: where do i put the <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> thing?

Comment: It didn't work - I put both <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> and thePlayer.delegate = self;

Comment: i never set up isplaying and mute - are they required to override? what methods should i post? THanks for your time and help so far by the way